# Armadillo : use of sp_mat

Tags: c++, matrix, sparse-matrix, armadillo

I have a problem with sparse matrix in Armadillo. 
I installed Armadillo library on my computer (I use Ubuntu 12.10 and Codeblock) and I can use matrix, eigen value and others functions of Armadillo, but when I use for exemple:

> sp_mat D;

or

> sp_mat D(N,N);

to declare D as sparse matrix, I read the followings errors:

> diag_periodique.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
>   diag_periodique.cpp:194:5: erreur: ‘sp_mat’ was not declared in this
>   scope diag_periodique.cpp:194:12: erreur: expected ‘;’ before ‘D’
>   diag_periodique.cpp:195:5: erreur: ‘D’ was not declared in this scope

I tried to compile using shell (and not Codeblock) with the following command:

> g++ Prog.cpp -o Prog -l armadillo

But it didn't work either and I got the same errors.

Do you know what is the problem ? 
I need to construct a big Matrix and to obtain its eigen value. Without Sparse matrix, I have a core dump error or somethinh like that.

Thanks

Comment: You need to include the necessary header file(s) and tell the compiler that `sp_mat` lives in `namespace arma`. That is, try `arma::sp_mat D;`.

Comment: Ubuntu has old versions of Armadillo in its software collection. The old versions of Armadillo do not have sparse matrix support. Remove the Ubuntu version of Armadillo, and then manually install the latest version of Armadillo from [here](http://arma.sourceforge.net/download.html).

Comment: Thank you. Indeed,it was an old version of Armadillo. I compiled the new and that works.